# Загрузка сайта с кириллическими URL

Tags: кодировка, wget

Загружаю часть сайта с `Windows` ПК. Для корректного сохранения файлов использую опцию `--restrict-file-names=windows`. При загрузке одной страницы все работает:

```
wget.exe https://morphemeonline.ru/А  --restrict-file-names=windows
--2021-10-29 19:38:41--  https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%90
Resolving morphemeonline.ru (morphemeonline.ru)... 178.208.83.23
Connecting to morphemeonline.ru (morphemeonline.ru)|178.208.83.23|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'А'
```

При рекурсивной загрузке с опцией `--recursive` портится не только имя файла (А / Рђ), но и запрашиваемый URL (%D0%90 / %D0%A0%D1%92).

```
wget.exe https://morphemeonline.ru/А  --restrict-file-names=windows --recursive
--2021-10-29 19:41:29--  https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%A0%D1%92
Resolving morphemeonline.ru (morphemeonline.ru)... 178.208.83.23
Connecting to morphemeonline.ru (morphemeonline.ru)|178.208.83.23|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Saving to: 'morphemeonline.ru/Рђ'
```

Часть лога по запросу 404.html скипнута.

```
wget.exe --version
GNU Wget 1.21.2 built on mingw32.
```

От порядка аргументов поведение не зависит. Как правильно загрузить такой сайт?

UPD: Кураторами была предложена метка cygwin. Поясню. Версия wget скопилирована под Windows. Никакой дополнительной среды не требует. Загружена с сайта https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ но может быть получено через Chocolatey packet manager.